# Does potential voltage affect a relay?

Tags: relay

If you have a mechanical relay rated at 600 V in an open position and then apply 1200 V to its contacts, but no current flows through them (say from a hipot machine,) does this result in damage to the relay?

I assumed not because I figured heat wouldn't build up until current passed through, but I thought it was worth asking to see if anyone has any experience in this.

Comment: A hipot may well have been the device used to generate the 600V limit, no??

Comment: Generally the primary ratings are by design, with margin, whereas the hipot is verification on real devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The insulation will be rated for a maximum continual voltage of 600V, as will the contact air gap.

At some voltage above the rated limit, the insulation may fail catastrophically.  Whether 1200V on a 600V device will cause such failure is unclear in the general case.

However, some devices also quote a "pulse withstand" voltage, which says they will cope with a higher voltage for a short period of time.  This is both for surge protection in general, but can be explicitly for HiPot testing.  If you have this for the device in question, you may therefore have a definitive answer.

(As noted in another answer, 600V AC rating will probably be okay with 1200V DC for testing, as peak voltage for AC is much higher than 600V AC.  However, this isn't the case for all devices, and historically many RCDs rated for 600V AC had a requirement to be disconnected before 1200V DC HiPot testing.)

Comment: Are you saying that the air gap insulation is included in the 600V rating? I had assumed the voltage to prevent contact welding was probably much lower than what would be required to cross an air gap. If the 600 V  to jump the gap is included then, this would lead me to believe the manufacturers design the air gap jump voltage to be inline with the contact welding voltage. Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: The air gap dimensions are often set to meet a variety of constraints, including simple breakdown, but for power relays isolation distance (which has to allow for vibration, dirt, mechanical variation, wear, etc) is often the key requirement.  Isolation distance _is_ different for different voltages, but it is more than just the air gap breakdown voltage.

Answer (score 3):

If that is *rated for 600VAC continuously*, then the peaks of that are \$\cdot \sqrt{2}\$ = 848.5VDC and 1200VDC is not far above this, so is unlikely to damage it for a quick test.

But statically this is still exceeding the rating, and if that were applied for some long amount of time (perhaps years), the insulation could eventually fail (catastrophically.)

Comment: DC voltage ratings for relay contacts and switches usually are _lower_ than the AC voltage rating for the same switch or relay. That's because a continuous DC arc is harder to extinguish than a pulsating AC arc.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That's correct but without the contacts closing the difficult of damping the arc doesn't matter (provided the voltage isn't high enough to arc in the first place, but that wouldn't matter if it was AC or DC then)